# 180 degree rotation matchstick equality

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, matches

Several matchstick digits are still digits when rotated by 180 degrees:

[image: invertible matchstick digits]

Note that 2 is rotated to 2.

[image: 2 to 2]

Thus, we can make a matchstick arithmetic expression which is valid when rotated 180 degrees. For example, 1+1=2.

[image: 1+1=2]

But, this is trivial because two expressions are the same.

The following matchstick expression produces two different valid equalities: 10+02=12 and 21=20+01.

[image: 10+02=12,21=20+01]

But, it's not natural because of the leading 0.

Can you find a natural matchstick arithmetic expression which produces two different valid equalities when rotated 180 degrees?

Maybe, the smallest answer is 0+6=6 which is turned into 9=9+0. Or 1x6=6 which is turned into 9=9x1. But, let us exclude trivial equalities like "0+...", "0x...", or "1x..."

Comment: Your equations don't work, 2 becomes 5, and 5 ~= 1 + 1

Comment: @warspyking So I eagerly drew the picture. :-) 2 is rotated to become 2. 5 is rotated to become 5. The mirror image of 2 is 5 and vice versa.

Comment: Shouldn't the question be "Create an equation" instead of "Create an expression"?

Comment: From your wording of the question it is currently *not* clear you want the *smallest* number(s) in your equation. Rephrase?

Comment: Maybe use "rotated upside down" instead of "turns upside down" to have things even more clearly stated.

Comment: @pacoverflow Thank you for correcting my poor English.

Comment: Many experts proposed beautiful answers. Why don't you find an answer using only one operation? A trivial example: 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=8.

Comment: It's not interesting because no number changes value.  Reversed it is exactly the same numbers added to the same sum.

Comment: @FlorianF Of course, I have a _nontrivial_ solution using only two + signs. :-)

Comment: This is really clever, OP!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This first answer is kind of boring, but I think multiplication answers will be hard to come by:

> 11 x 6 = 66
>  99 = 9 x 11
>  You can have as many 1s as you like in one term. Also you can add as many extra x1 terms on either side as you want, just as you can add +0

(Removed an incorrect solution that assumed 2 rotated to 5. Erk).

Here's a more interesting one:

> 65 + 2 x 6 + 99 - 66 = 58 + 52
>  25 + 85 = 99 - 66 + 9 x 2 + 59

---

Edit: And here's another extendable answer:

> 66 + 55 - 22 = 99
>  66 = 22 - 55 + 99
>  You can do this with any number of digits.

Comment: Good! I believed that your answer of 1-digit numbers was the smallest. Meelo and supercat created the smaller ones, though.

Answer (score 14):

I'll start the ball rolling...

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Great rolling! But the smaller number can be expressed.

Answer (score 11):

What answer is "best" depends on how one defines "trivial", but if the goal is to have an answer which uses different arithmetical relationships when inverted, how about

```
 21-9                                   5-11
------ = 8-6    which becomes    9-8 = ------
 11-5                                   6-12
```

The values before and after inversion are different, and the things that make one side different have no analog on the other side (whereas in e.g. something like 26+12 = 16+22, the left-side "6" becoming a nine is balanced by having the right-side six become a nine).

Comment: "Best" answer would vary under various conditions. Maybe Callidus' answer would be the best of the those form using only +/-. I didn't thought of the fantastic answer as yours.

Answer (score 8):

> 65+2-5 = 5-2+59

Technically, it is not a *different* equality.  But I believe it is in the spirit of the puzzle.

If not, just write

> 65+2-5 = 55+5+2
>  2+5+55 = 5-2+59

Another solution:

> 25-19 = 6

Comment: I like your answer! :-)

The last simplest answer is the same as Callidus.

Comment: Indeed, so I changed it.

Comment: I especially like 25-19 = 6 since none of the numbers appear in the rotated version.

Answer (score 6):

$$6+6-5=5+1+(1+1)-1$$
Rotates to
$$1-(1+1)+1+5=5-9+9$$

Comment: It's better to change (1+1) to 2. I don't know how to depict parantheses by matchsticks. :-)

Anyway, it's a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about.

> $$0=28^0-28^0$$
> $$0^{82}-0^{82}=0$$

Comment: To be fair, it's only marginally not-an-answer. The two equalities it yields are essentially 1-1=0 and 0-0=0, which are indeed different. But I think they fall into the same "trivial" category as ones of the form x+0=x, explicitly excluded in the question.

Comment: @Gareth Check out [the revision history](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/41966/revisions) of this answer: originally it was of the 'trivial' type explicitly excluded by the question, which was why I flagged it as NaA, but now I think it's OK.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. I should have thought of that.